# What is the correct way of enumerating an array?

Tags: go

While reading the [strconv package](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/strconv/atoi_test.go), I noticed that the enumeration to test cases is implemented like: [link](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/strconv/atoi_test.go#L322)

```
    for i := range parseInt64Tests {
      test := &parseInt64Tests[i]
      if test.err != nil {
        test.err = &NumError{"ParseInt", test.in, test.err}
      }
    }
```

I was very confused of `&parseInt64Tests[i]`. Why not just `for i := range parseInt64Tests`?

I wrote my own test to check if the for loop returns the original array items or a new copy.

```
var calculationTests = []calculationCases {
    {0,0, nil},
    {8,0, nil},
    {9,1,nil},
    {11, 1, nil },
    {12, 2, nil },
    {14, 2, nil },
    {1969, 654, nil },
    {100756, 33583, nil },
 }

 func TestCalculate(t *testing.T) {
    for i, test := range calculationTests {
        if &calculationTests[i] != &test {
           t.Errorf("items not equal %v %v %p, %p", test, calculationTests[i], &test, &calculationTests[i])
        }

    } 
 }
```

the output was like the following:

```
--- FAIL: TestCalculate (0.00s)
fule_test.go:25: array item not same {0 0 <nil>} {0 0 <nil>} 0xc0000a4040, 0x12306a0
fule_test.go:25: array item not same {8 0 <nil>} {8 0 <nil>} 0xc0000a4040, 0x12306c0
fule_test.go:25: array item not same {9 1 <nil>} {9 1 <nil>} 0xc0000a4040, 0x12306e0
fule_test.go:25: array item not same {11 1 <nil>} {11 1 <nil>} 0xc0000a4040, 0x1230700
fule_test.go:25: array item not same {12 2 <nil>} {12 2 <nil>} 0xc0000a4040, 0x1230720
fule_test.go:25: array item not same {14 2 <nil>} {14 2 <nil>} 0xc0000a4040, 0x1230740
fule_test.go:25: array item not same {1969 654 <nil>} {1969 654 <nil>} 0xc0000a4040, 0x1230760
fule_test.go:25: array item not same {100756 33583 <nil>} {100756 33583 <nil>} 0xc0000a4040, 0x1230780
FAIL
exit status 1
```

It proves the `for loop` returns a copy, not the original instance.

My question is: what is the best practice of looping an array, should I always use indexer instead of an enumerator?

Comment: The expression `&calculationTests[i]` is the address of the slice element.  The expression `&test` is the address of local variable `test`.  Because the goal of the code is to modify the slice elements, the address of the slice element is used.

Comment: Neither is preferable in all cases; it depends on the slice element type and what you want to do with it. Here the slice elements are modified, so it's convenient to use a pointer to the elements. But that doesn't generalize.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks for your comment. is the local variable `test` a copy of the the slice element or a pointer to the element item? I am sorry, as a .net developer, I am not confident about my understanding to pointers

Comment: @AwakeningByte It's a shallow copy, pointers inside the type will still point to the same data in copy var `test`. You can assume `test := parseInt64Tests[i]` for each iteration.

Comment: @ferhatelmas thanks for the answer. Can you add it to answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @AwakeningByte  Yes, the local variable `test` is a copy of the slice element. Values are copied in assignments as is the case for many other programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: what is the best practice of looping an array, should I always use indexer instead of an enumerator?

I think it depends on your use case.

In the `strconv` package case, the authors want to **modify** the global scoped `parseInt64Tests` array, so they chose to use index number that access the original member of the array and then modifies them.

Whereas if the authors uses enumerator, they can't modify the original `parseInt64Tests` array because the enumerator returns a copy of each member of the array; if they get the address from that copy by using `&`, it will return another address and not the original.

In general, if you want to modify or mutates state of enclosing variable (variables outside the loop) use index. If not, use enumerator.

here is the example: https://play.golang.org/p/EItIKpWU_qK

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    Value int
}

var modifyMe = []Data{
    {Value: 0},
    {Value: 1},
    {Value: 2},
    {Value: 3},
    {Value: 4},
    {Value: 5},
    {Value: 6},
    {Value: 7},
    {Value: 8},
}

func main() {
    // modify()
    notModify()
    fmt.Println(modifyMe)
}

func modify() {
    for i, _ := range modifyMe {
        refToModifyMeData := &modifyMe[i]
        refToModifyMeData.Value =  refToModifyMeData.Value + 100
    }
}

func notModify() {
    for _, data := range modifyMe {
        refToModifyMeData := &data  
        refToModifyMeData.Value =  refToModifyMeData.Value + 100
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is actually one that's differentiate between functional and imperative programming. Not so much about the go itself. But go lang is very much supportive of those two.

Answer (score 1):

The article https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes provides the clear description that what critical cases happen while playing with arrays in loop in go.

You can check the section

> Using reference to loop iterator variable

As mentioned above, `&calculationTests[i]` is the address of the slice element. So everytime it will give error if you compare the address of slice with the address of local variable. If you want to compare the values, then you can do it like

```
if calculationTests[i] != test {
     t.Errorf("items not equal %v %v %p, %p", test, calculationTests[i], &test, &calculationTests[i])
}
```